# Nandroid Backup Fails with extractTarFork() error

Tags: backup, nandroid

Long story short, I tried to install MultiROM on my Nexus 6P, and it failed.  So I tried to restore my backup using TWRP 3.0.2.0, and it keeps failing at exactly 7800MB with the error `E:extractTarFork() process ended with ERROR=255`.  I have seen posts talking about checking the log when this happens, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

What exactly do I need to do to restore my backup?

I guess I should add some detail.  I first tried booting to recovery and restoring the backup.  The phone rebooted into a boot loop part of the way through the restore process every time I tried that.  Then, I tried flashing the phone completely back to the stock image, and then restoring.  I got the error 255 above.  Then, I tried flashing back to stock completely, wiping Dalvik/cache, and restoring the backup.  I still get the same error message.  I tried restoring everything except userdata, and the phone reboots part of the way through the restore.

I could easily reroot, reinstall Xposed, and reflash TWRP if for some reason my system backup partition is corrupted.  However, I don't want to lose my data partition at all.  That was the whole reason I made the backup in the first place.